# Trying to compare two dataframes with different rows and columns in R

Tags: r, compare

I am trying to compare two different dataframes which have different columns and rows in R.
Need to get the same data be df3, any row or column are different data be df4.In my example, id F, col1 and col2 in both two tables is the same.but other cols are not.

Below is what my dataset looks like:

```
set.seed(22)

df1 <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS, 9, FALSE), col1=sample(0:2, 9, TRUE),
                  col2 = sample(0:2, 9, TRUE))
df2 <- data.frame(id=sample(LETTERS, 17, FALSE), col1=sample(0:2, 17, TRUE),
                  col2 = sample(0:2, 17, TRUE),
                  col6 = sample(0:2, 17, TRUE))
```

df1
[image]

df2
[image]

I've read many solutions but have not yet found a concise solution, any suggestions out there? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can there be duplicated rows within `df1` or `df2`, and should they be filtered before performing the comparison? Also, do you need to have `col6` in the result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `generics::intersect()` to find the common values and `generics::setdiff()` to find the different values. Note you need to specify the `generics` package to get it in the format you want.

```
df3 <- generics::intersect(df1, df2[,1:3])
  #    id col1 col2
  # 1  F    1    0
  # 2  K    0    2

df4 <- generics::setdiff(df1, df2[,1:3])
  # id col1 col2
  #1  I    1    2
  #2  X    2    0
  #3  J    0    2
  #4  L    0    1
  #5  Q    1    0
  #6  E    1    0
  #7  C    1    0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `tidyverse` or `dplyr` you can use `semi_join` and `anti_join`. You will need to specify the columns you want to use to perform the comparison using parameter `by`: `by = c("id", "col1", "col2")`. (You can leave `by` unspecified and `*_join` will perform the comparison using all matching colnames, but this is better avoided.)

`semi_join` returns all rows from the first data.frame **with** a match in the second data.frame:

```r
library(dplyr)
# Or:
# library(tidyverse)

# We'll pass df2 as the first argument, to preserve the values in `col6`.
# Swap the order of `df2` and `df1` to drop column `col6`.
df3 <- semi_join(df2, df1, by = c("id", "col1", "col2"))

df3
#   id col1 col2 col6
# 1  K    0    2    2
# 2  F    1    0    2
```

`anti_join` returns all rows from the first data.frame **without** a match in the second data.frame. This one is a bit trickier because we'll only get the rows in the **first** data.frame that are missing in the **second**. To get the rows that are present in any of the data.frames but missing in the other, we need to perform the join twice:

```r
library(dplyr)
# Or:
# library(tidyverse)

df4_a <- anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("id", "col1", "col2"))
df4_b <- anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("id", "col1", "col2"))

df4 <- bind_rows(df4_a, df4_b)

df4
#    id col1 col2 col6
# 1   I    1    2   NA
# 2   X    2    0   NA
# 3   J    0    2   NA
# 4   L    0    1   NA
# 5   Q    1    0   NA
# 6   E    1    0   NA
# 7   C    1    0   NA
# 8   Y    1    0    2
# 9   T    2    1    0
# 10  P    2    0    1
# 11  A    1    2    1
# 12  R    2    0    0
# 13  V    2    1    1
# 14  M    0    0    1
# 15  S    1    2    2
# 16  O    0    0    2
# 17  B    2    0    0
# 18  U    0    1    0
# 19  W    1    1    2
# 20  G    1    2    1
# 21  H    2    1    0
# 22  C    2    0    1
```

Also, you can get `df4` more concisely if you don't store the intermediate results:

```r
library(dplyr)
# Or:
# library(tidyverse)

df4 <- bind_rows(
  anti_join(df1, df2, by = c("id", "col1", "col2")),
  anti_join(df2, df1, by = c("id", "col1", "col2"))
)

df4
#    id col1 col2 col6
# 1   I    1    2   NA
# 2   X    2    0   NA
# 3   J    0    2   NA
# 4   L    0    1   NA
# 5   Q    1    0   NA
# 6   E    1    0   NA
# 7   C    1    0   NA
# 8   Y    1    0    2
# 9   T    2    1    0
# 10  P    2    0    1
# 11  A    1    2    1
# 12  R    2    0    0
# 13  V    2    1    1
# 14  M    0    0    1
# 15  S    1    2    2
# 16  O    0    0    2
# 17  B    2    0    0
# 18  U    0    1    0
# 19  W    1    1    2
# 20  G    1    2    1
# 21  H    2    1    0
# 22  C    2    0    1
```

Comment: There is a function `symdiff` that should be able to do both antijoins. eg `symdiff(df1, df2[names(df1)])` Though it will not have col 6